# I want to ask a question about verbal noun

Tags: gerunds

Recently I have studied about the differences between a verbal noun with the *-ing* suffix and a gerund. I know that we can use the articles and the preposition "of" with a verbal noun but we can't use these both with a gerund. But I still have problem with using it. For example, are we allowed to use the *-ing* form of any verb along with the articles and the preposition "of"?

For example, in the phrase *"the abating of the storm"*, is "abating" a gerund or a verbal noun? If it is a gerund, are we allowed to use all verbs in this form?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give some examples in your question.

Comment: For example in sentence "the abating of the storm" , "abating"   is a gerund or a verbal noun. If it is a gerund, are we allowed to use all verb in this form?

Comment: If they make sense, sure. *The winning of the war*, *the branding of cattle*, *the dealing of cards*, etc., are all fine.

Comment: Thank you Robusto . So are this word you mentioned  are verbal noun or gerund?

Comment: You ask if _abating_ is a "gerund or a verbal noun", but a gerund **is** a verbal noun. There is no difference between the two. A **gerund** is what we call the noun form of a verb. Every verb has its gerund. That gerund can be used like any other noun. Just as we can talk about _the ferocity of the storm,_ we can talk about _the abating of the storm._ There's nothing special about using _of_ or any other preposition after a gerund. We can say _coming **to** the house_ or _leaving **for** the city_ or _running **over** a cat._

Comment: P. E. Dant's comment is incorrect; for details please see http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48770/a-gerund-is-not-a-noun  In *the abating of the storm*, it is a noun rather than a gerund, which we can tell because it has the form of a noun phrase, complete with a determiner and *of*-phrase, because it takes adjectival rather than adverbial modification, and so on.

Comment: **A gerund is always a noun and verb at the same time. It is type of verbal noun, a noun that has verbal properties as well.** This is an elegant and useful way to think of the gerund. For an explanation, see tchrist's answer at ELU [**here.**](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/205404/192771)

Comment: I can't help but think this question is better suited for ELU since few native speakers are going to care to split these hairs.

Answer (score 1):

If you can put a determiner in front of it, then it's a noun.

> The running was hard on his body. (verbal noun)
>
> Him giving her the money made his mom mad. (gerund)
>
> His backtalking resulted in punishment. (verbal noun)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following may help everyone here:

> "A verbal noun is a noun that has no verb-like properties despite being derived from a verb. This means that a verbal noun can be modified by adjectives, be pluralized (if the sense allows), and be followed by a prepositional phrase." (Source:
>   http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/verbal_nouns.htm)

While...

> "A verbal noun is different from a gerund. A gerund is a noun that, having derived from a verb, retains a few verb-like properties. For example, a gerund can be modified by an adverb and can take a direct object." (Source:
>   http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/verbal_nouns.htm)

Please take a look at the source URL for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Gerund and verbal nouns are lookalikes. If we consider their origins and functions they are identical twins with the only difference that verbal nouns appear commonly prefixed by ' the ' and followed by 'of'; but that's not the rule of thumb.

- We are waiting for the abating of the storm.(VN)
- He likes reading books {books for reading (G)}.

Better is it to say that Gerunds are double parts of speech (both verb and noun) whereas Verbal nouns become absolute nouns and loses the verbal identity altogether. It is better to put your -ing word to the acid test as suggested by LawrenceC hereinabove.